# ASP.NET The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

This should be very simple, but im notsure what is wrong.

Every time i try and access "http://localhost:50949/api/projects", i get the following error

The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

ApiController

```
private const string m_BaseUrl = "http://example.com/rest/api/2/";
    private string m_Username = Properties.Settings.Default.username;
    private string m_Password = Properties.Settings.Default.password;
    // GET: api/Projects       
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(JiraResource resource, string argument = null, string data = null, string method = "GET")
    {
        string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", m_BaseUrl, resource.ToString());

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;

        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        string result = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string GetEncodedCredentials()
    {
        string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", m_Username, m_Password);
        byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
    }
```

HTML/JS

```
<h2>Projects</h2>

<button id="projects" class="btn btn-info">List Projects</button>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
    $(document)
        .ready(function() {
            $("#projects")
                .click(function(e) {
                    var button = $(e.target);
                    $.get("/api/projects/")
                        .done(function() {                               
                            alert("Got Projects");
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                            alert("Something failed!");
                        });
                });
        });
</script>

}
```

If i do it through the UI i get "Something Failed"

Comment: None of the actions you have match `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}` that is why it doesn't see your  method.

Comment: everything looks fine, what are you saying i should change?

Comment: `resource` parameter is not optional so it does not match the route template you have. You either update your route template or update the action parameters.

Comment: but my route template says id = RouteParameter.Optional

Comment: Correct, which means it's looking for an action with either a parameter called `id` that it can default to it's default value as it is optional or an action with no parameters. neither of which you have.

Comment: What is the expected behavior when you call `http://localhost:50949/api/projects`? How is `resource` populated? You will get a NRE on the first line of the method if `resource` is `null`.

Comment: yes, getting rid of the parameters worked

Answer (score 0):

In your method int the controller you still have to put the route attribute even if it is empty string:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get(JiraResource resource, string argument = null, string data = null, string method = "GET")
    {
...
    }
```